# Element_to_be_clickable not working

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to check whether a button is enabled on the screen. The problem I'm having is that the "element_to_be_clickable" function doesn't seem to be picking up that the button is clickable.

My code looks as follows:

```
                #check if the button is clickable
            try:
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID(button_id)))
                button_status_screen = True

            except Exception as e:
                button_status_screen = False

            # assert button enabled status on screen == expected status
            button_status_screen = str(button_status_screen).strip()                                                
            Myresult = False                                                                                        #compare the expected result to the actual result
            if button_status_excel == button_status_screen:
                Myresult = True

            assert Myresult == True, "Button was not enabled or disabled as expected."
```

When the button is enabled, the try still goes to the exception and sets "button_status_screen to false (I'm expecting it to be set to true and skip over the exception).

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Why not use .Enabled method on the element directly?

Comment: Thanks, I was avoiding using "is_enabled" (because of something I'd read earlier), but that solved the issue.